# sublime text 3 "window tab" switch keyboard shortcut

Tags: sublimetext3, shortcut

I haven't found the keyboard shortcut to switch between "a" "b" "c" tabs(windows), do you known?

There is the screenshot image.

[is there any keyboard shortcut to switch between "a" "b" "c" tabs(windows)?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NKyo.jpg)

---

Update:

This package is what I want.

packagecontrol.io/packages/GotoWindow

Perfect!

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/switch-windows-shortcut/10834

Comment: Those tabs are MacOS's way of representing multiple windows in one; as such if there's a keystroke to swap between them it would be a MacOS keyboard shortcut and not a Sublime one. I don't know if such a hotkey exists though; my version of MacOS is old enough to not support that feature.

Comment: @OdatNurd Ok, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For Sublime Text 3 in Windows and Linux, the keyboard shortcuts to move back/forth through tabs are as follows:

Move forward a tab = `Ctrl` + `tab`

Move to previous tab = `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `tab`

You can also use `Alt` + `[1-9]` to move to the specific number tab that you want (tab 1, tab 2, etc).

I learned this from Wes Bos' Sublime Text Power User guide. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! The 'tabs' in my problem is not the 'tabs' in your answer.

Comment: this actually cycles through the 'views in stack' which means if you've rearranged your tabs, this will jump all over the place and make no damn sense.  what you want is 'next-view' and 'prev-view' which are 'ctrl+page up/down' respectively.

Comment: anyone have a solution for ctrl+pgup / ctrl+pgdown on a macbook (no pgup and pgdown keys)? edit: just saw sqn answer below - command+shift+[ / command+shift+]

Answer (score 1):

Well if your on Mac just use the following it will work:

```
"command+shift+[" to go to previous tab 
"command+shift+]" to move to the next tab
```

These are the defaults, if want you can customize them. Just to go preferences and then Key Bindings add your own bindings.